Integrating $\int_0^{\arctan(\rho/z)} \sec\phi\,\ln\left[1+\cos\left(2a\left(b - \frac{c}{d}\sec\phi\right)\right)\right]d\phi$
I am unable to solve this directly using python's sympy library or  wolfram alpha.

I am also not able to simplify it any meaningful way.
Using techniques like $u$-substitution seems to make it even more complicated.
$$
\int_{0}^{\arctan\left(\rho/z\right)} \sec(\phi)\ln\left(1 +
\cos\left(2a\left[b -
\frac{c}{d_{const}}
\sec(\phi)\right]\right)\right)
{\rm d}\phi
$$
Could we rewrite it into another form that I am not aware of to make it solvable?


why do you believe it has a nice closed form?

@SineoftheTime I forgot to add the domain, I just added it. Does it still have an open form?

Is there any reason tk believe it can be evaluated using elementary functions?

@Clayton I am still new to this and I am not sure how to recognize non analytical integrals. Are you able to provide any insight on this?

It is up to you to provide context. Is it a homework problem? Contest problem? Is it FROM something that would lead you to believe it can be evaluated?

@Clayton As my username suggests, this is a hobby I do...

Why do you ask for a definite integral since $\rho$ and $z$ do not appear in the integrand ?

@ClaudeLeibovici The original problem was in my question here and answered here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4986780/681694. The original problem was in cylindrical coordinates but then transformed into spherical.

@Mathaholic what is an "open form"?

@SineoftheTime It means it is not solvable analytically. That is what you were implying in your first comment?

@Mathaholic See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression

Using complex analysis i only went up to this:
The integral is:
$$\int_{0}^{\arctan\left(\frac{\rho}{z}\right)} \sec(\phi) \ln\left[1 + \cos\left(2a(b - \frac{c}{d} \cdot \sec(\phi))\right)\right] d\phi$$
Substituting trigonometric functions using the complex exponential form for:
$$\sec(\phi) = \frac{1}{\cos(\phi)} = \frac{2}{e^{i\phi} + e^{-i\phi}}$$
$$\int_{0}^{\arctan\left(\frac{\rho}{z}\right)} \frac{2}{e^{i\phi} + e^{-i\phi}} \ln\left[1 + \frac{\exp{i(2a(b - \frac{c}{d} \cdot \frac{2}{e^{i\phi} + e^{-i\phi}}))} + \exp{-i(2a(b - \frac{c}{d} \cdot \frac{2}{e^{i\phi} + e^{-i\phi}}))}}{2}\right] d\phi$$
Identifying the real part
Firstly separating the real part of the integrand. It's complex exponentials, so in fact i evaluated it to:
$$\frac{2}{e^{i\phi} + e^{-i\phi}} = \sec(\phi)$$
Simplifying the Logarithmic Term
The logarithmic term can be simplified using properties of logarithms and trigonometric identities. It evaluates to:
$$\ln \left[1 + \frac{ \exp{i(2a(b - \frac{c}{d} \cdot \frac{2}{e^{i\phi} + e^{-i\phi}}))} + \exp{-i(2a(b - \frac{c}{d} \cdot \frac{2} {e^{i\phi} + e^{-i\phi}}))}}{2} \right]$$
Contour Integration appropriating for the  possibility integrand has singularities on the real axis
Applying the Residue Theorem
The poles occur where the denominator $e^{i\phi}$ + $e^{-i\phi} = 0$, which simplifies to $e^{2i\phi} = -1\\$, giving $\phi = \pi$
Calculating the residue at: $\phi = \pi$
Finding the residue of $\sec(\phi)\\$ at $\phi = \pi$:
$$\sec(\phi) = \frac{1}{\cos(\phi)}$$
At $\phi = \pi, \cos(\pi) = -1, so \sec(\pi) = -1$
Evaluating the logarithmic term at $\phi = \pi$:
Substitute $\phi = \pi\\$ into the logarithmic term and simplifying
Summation of the residues and multiply by $2\pi i\\$ obtaining the value of the integral

I disagree with the residue at $\phi = \pi$ since I looked it up https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=exp%282ix%29+%3D+-1
